# How to remove borders in first row in multiple sheets using vba

Tags: vba, excel

How to remove borders in first row in multiple sheets. Number of columns is variable for every sheet.

Comment: What is the best way to learn [VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2901783/1490783)? Please read the part about recording a macro, that should get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use vba? Assuming all worksheet are the same format, select all worksheet tabs and make a change to one.   It would take you longer to write the code then to just do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Remove_Border()

Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim Colletter As String

For Each ws In Worksheets

 With ws
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Colletter = Split(.Cells(, LastCol).Address, "$")(1)
 End With

ws.Range("A1:" & Colletter & "1").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
Next ws
End Sub
```